# Correct way to use the OutDir - load and archive file test: with Teamcity and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, teamcity

**Background**

I have an import process, which includes uploading a couple of files, which then go into an "Import" folder, the user then processes the files (get put into the database), which then get put into an "Archive" folder.

**Problem**

Running tests for this process, is where I'm encountering the problem.

The test import files for this are stored in a "Resources" (including Import and Archive) folder within the Tests project within the Visual Studio solution.

**Current Solution: Attempt**

A post-build event has been setup on the project to xcopy the "Resources" folder to the ${Outdir} - this works great in Visual Studio.

**Problem**

When I run Teamcity, the solution build - creates the folder (and subfolders) in /bin/Release/ rather than Teamcity's /out/ directory.

I'm sure I'm just not doing the copy in the correct way, there have been some suggestions of using MSBuild rather than xcopy, so could do with some help.

How do I setup Teamcity / my Solution to build to output these test files to the same place.

Answer (score 1):

Using TeamCity

You can override the build output path by passing in the parameter to msbuild - this will override the project settings.

In the MsBuild / Visual Studio runner step, add this into the Command Line Parameters field

```
/p:OutputPath=out
```

The other alternative is to edit the project file in an editor and change the path there.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>out\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will ensure that all files are output to a directory that is consistent whether you are building in Visual Studio or TeamCity

To get your test files into this directory, I would set the build action on them to Content and to copy if newer.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This hasn't resolved the issue, but I'm now taking a proper look at msbuild. As xcopy doesn't seem to be a good idea.  The problem isn't just copying the files, its having the complete structure, including empty folders such as /Resources/Archive.

Comment: There are ways of doing this, but I don't know how much you want to "muddy" your project. If you create an empty directory structure (e.g. Resources/Archive) in your project and place a text file at the lowest level that has the same properties as the screenshot, this will recreate the directory structure within the build output. This isn't perfect though because you may have a more complex directory structure, but it might be a quick win for you.

Comment: This is actually what I did previously. But Teamcity can't find the files - it seems to ignore this part of the process.

Comment: When you say TeamCity can't find the file, am I assuming correctly that there's another step / build configuration referencing these files? Things to check would be the Working Directory for the steps. Are there multiple build agents? MsBuild will do what it's told so without fully knowing the setup it's hard to guess at what may now be the issue. Check the logs in the build tabs to ensure you see the files being copied out.